# Django router withe multiple tables

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I settled a django router to link my datatables to the rest api. To do so, I have my models given by:

```
class Lab(models.Model):
    nom = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ville = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

and its serialization method like this:

```
class LabSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Lab
        fields = ('url', 'nom', 'ville', 'pk')
```

To access this table, I created a ViewSet in a views file like this :

```
class LabViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Lab.objects.all()
    serializer_class = LabSerializer
```

And in the urls file, I register my view like this :

```
router.register('labs', LabViewSet)
```

This is working, but I'd like to add a new table, Member, linked to the Lab table :

```
class Member(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField()
    nom = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    prenom = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    lab = models.ForeignKey(Lab, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

How can I access the data throuht a single request joining both tables ?

Comment: You are probably searching for [**DRF Nested Serializers**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships)

Answer (score 0):

You can define another serializer for `Member` like this

```
class MemberSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Member
        fields = ('email', 'nom', 'prenom')
```

and attach it to `LabSerializer`

```
class LabSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    members = MemberSerializer(many=True, read_only=True, source='member_set')
    class Meta:
        model = Lab
        fields = ('url', 'nom', 'ville', 'pk', 'members')
```

Please note that it will run n+1 queries on database. So override `get_queryset`in ViewSet like this for query optimization

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return Lab.objects.select_related('member_set')
```